# Flutter - overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter, dart

I have problem with overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom. I'm find many solution but again not working.

This is my details page.

```
class MyWidgetApiDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final Emp emp;
  const MyWidgetApiDetails({Key key, @required this.emp}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('DETAILS EMP'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Hero(
              tag: emp.empno,
              child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                  child: Image.network(emp.image))
          ),
          Container(
            height: 20,
            width: 100,
            child: PhotoView(
              imageProvider: AssetImage("assets/images/map.jpg"),
            ),
          ),
          PhotoView(
            imageProvider: NetworkImage(emp.image),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Text(
            emp.empno.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Text(
            emp.ename,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When put Column in SingleChildScrollView get RenderFlex object was given an infinite size during layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by just changing from Column to ListView.

```
class MyWidgetApiDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final Emp emp;
  const MyWidgetApiDetails({Key key, @required this.emp}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('DETAILS EMP'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Hero(
              tag: emp.empno,
              child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                  child: Image.network(emp.image))
          ),
          Container(
            height: 20,
            width: 100,
            child: PhotoView(
              imageProvider: AssetImage("assets/images/map.jpg"),
            ),
          ),
          PhotoView(
            imageProvider: NetworkImage(emp.image),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Text(
            emp.empno.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Text(
            emp.ename,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: when put in LIstView get RenderIndexedSemantics object was given an infinite size during layout.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `SingleChildScrollView` wants to be as large as possible, you need to put it into something that has constraints, like a `Column`, you could do something like this:

```
//pseudocode, not sure about the exact syntax.
body: Expanded(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(...)
    )
  ]
)
```

And I believe it should work.
Take a look [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints) and [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) for more information.

Comment: when use your example get  again RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense it should probably be a container just as you did or you could try to wrap it in a Expanded widget. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put Column in SingleChildScrollView  and wrap PhotoView in Container solve my problem.